# Unable to format a Linux bootable USB under Windows

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, formatting

I recently installed Ubuntu onto my 16GB Kingston USB stick. My laptop uses Windows 10.

After I tried to boot into Ubuntu from the USB stick, it displayed an error. I then restarted my laptop and booted Windows 10. I tried to reformat the Kingston USB stick and it says that it is unable to be formatted as there is no media.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is considered on-topic as it is essentially a software request. I would suggest you try formatting the drive with SDFormatter, a free formatter by the SD consortium. https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/ – it has always worked for me when others have failed.

Answer (score 0):

Though normally it shouldn't happen, it is a common issue, because of the changed partition setup windows format tool sometimes does not recognize the USB drive properly anymore.

A tool in my kit is the HP usb format tool.
http://download.cnet.com/HP-USB-Disk-Storage-Format-Tool/3000-2094_4-10974082.html
It should do the trick, be sure to launch it as administrator.

FYI: Often windows still can reformat the USB drive if you remove all individual partitions through the Disk manager ( windows key + x , disk management ).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`gparted` live cd](http://gparted.org/download.php) to re-create the partition table

Plug in your USB , from the menu, select **create the partition table** and **Apply**

Right clic on the unallocated partition >> select **New** then select the file system e,g : `Fat32` clic add then apply.